# How to Make Scroll Window Affect the Scroll Div Content?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

How do you make scrolling in Windows affect scrolling in div content such as WordPress editor pages.

For example I have an element:

1. Header
2. Article
3. Footer

My div content has style:

```
.my-div {
   overflow-y: auto;
   height: 576px;
}
```

Inside the `my-div`, there is an article that is 1000 characters long, which means there is a scroll there.

How do I make it when I scroll down, after passing the header and arrive at the article, the scroll will have an impact on the div content scroll that I have in there, in the `article` section.

```
<article>
    <div class="my-div">
        <!-- my content here -->
    </div>
</article>
```

So when I pull down the window scroll to the bottom, then my div scroll will be pulled down.

Until when my 'div' scroll has finished, automatically my scroll window that I pulled down will bring me to the `footer` section.

I have looked for a solution to this problem but I have not found it.

Thank you in advance.

*translated by: Google*

Answer (score 0):

This JS makes the element with an ID of `YOUR_ELEMENT` scroll with the window scroll.

```
const lastScrollTop = window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
   const st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
     document.getElementById('YOUR_ELEMENT').scrollTop++;
   } else {
      document.getElementById('YOUR_ELEMENT').scrollTop--
   }
   lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st; // For Mobile or negative scrolling
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks in advance for you response Sir, I've been try and I got something like this code: https://jsfiddle.net/tisufa/3cntdLvw/10/. Before myScroll content scrolled until 'myScroll' footer, The window scroll bring me to the footer content.

I Mean, how to make `myScroll` scrolled until `myScroll` bottom before my window scroll bring me to the my footer content.